# Dynamically Set Type of Prop Based on Another Prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I have an interface like the following:

```
interface Example {
    Component: React.ReactElement;
    componentProperties: typeof Example.Component;
}
```

Is there a way to get the type of the properties that that component passed in expects. So say I pass in a custom component like the following:

```
const Text = ({ value: string }) => <p>{value}</p>;
```

The type of componentProperties I would like to equal `{ value: string }`

---

I think I am looking something closer to this where the typeof the Component is what determines the type for componentProperties:

```
interface Example<T> {
    Component: () => React.ReactElement;
    componentProperties: T;
}

const Comp = ({ value }: { value: string}) => <p>{value}</p>;

const blah = ({ Component, componentProperties }: Example<typeof Component>) => {
    return <Component {...componentProperties} />;
};

blah({
    Component: Comp,
    componentProperties: { value: 'test' }
});
```

This example is riddled with errors which is why I am having trouble.

Comment: Should this have a `react` tag?  If not, then could you remove the apparent dependency on react from your question?

Answer (score 0):

this is a common use case for generics, eg:

```js
interface Example<T> {
    Component: React.ReactElement;
    componentProperties: T;
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except the blah, I would guess

there you get the errors.

This is how I solved this on my project.

```js
const blah = ({ Component, componentProperties }: Example<typeof Component>) => {
    var Cm = Component as any;
    return <Cm {...componentProperties} />;
};
```

Comment: Component as any seems to be to loose for me but I am interested in how you got the componentProperties set. Maybe there is something I can add to this. I will test it out a bit.

Comment: It is not loose. Try it and you will see that it works.